# Using python with tor: can't access .onion sites and I could be leaking private information

Tags: python, proxy, tor

I am building a program to fetch some content from a .onion website. I have managed to get the program to connect to tor and change its identity, but I get a warning that says I could be leaking private information. Worst of all, the program is failing to access .onion websites.

I have googled around a bit, but the only answer I could find is a bit convoluted and overly specific to the person's situation. The other solution I found was to make sure socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5 was there, instead of some other variant, but I already have that.

My current code:

```
import socket
import socks
import httplib
import urllib2
def getURLSource(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
def getURLSourceHTTPLIB(url):
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
    conn.request("GET","/")
    response = conn.getresponse()
    return response.read()
def connectTor():
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,"127.0.0.1",9050,True)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
def newIdentity():
    socks.setdefaultproxy()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1",9051))
    s.send("AUTHENTICATE\r\n")
    responce = s.recv(128)
    if responce.startswith("250"):
        s.send("SIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n")
    s.close()
    connectTor()
def fetchIP():
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("my-ip.heroku.com")
    conn.request("GET","/")
    response = conn.getresponse()
    return response.read()
def main():
    connectTor()
    print("Connected to Tor")
    print(fetchIP())
    #print(getSource("am4wuhz3zifexz5u.onion"))
    print(getURLSource("http://am4wuhz3zifexz5u.onion/Library/English/"))
main()
```

The warning message:
"[TIME AND DATE STAMP] Potentially Dangerous Connection! - One of your applications established a connection through Tor to "[CENSORED IP]" using a protocol that may leak information about your destination. Please ensure you configure your applications to use only SOCKS4a or SOCKS5 with remote hostname resolution."